# add/modify URL parameters

Tags: javascript, html, flask, python-3.5

I have a page with several graphs, I would like to have a drop down menu next to each graph that allows me to filter by different parameter. The problem I find myself against is figuring out an easy way to

> a) add a parameter to the current URL without deleting already existing parameters
>
> b) checking if that parameter is already in the URL and modify it.

I might also have anchors on my URLs. Is there a simple way of achieving this without needing to parse the whole URL myself?

This would be the dropdown menu I use for the filter, and the idea is to use request in python to get the URL parameters.

```
<select name ="date range" onchange="this.form.submit()">
   <option value="today">Today</option>
   <option value="current week">Current week</option>
   <option value="last week">Last week</option>
   <option value="current month">Current month</option>
   <option value="last month">Last month</option>
</select>
```

Right now I've been using just URL parameters for this tasks but now I need to up my game a little bit and make it prettier

Comment: I've thought of using hidden parameters, but I would need to be able to check the URL for each of the paramaters, if they have an assigned value and if they are not in the URL give them no value and I assign the default value in my python script

Comment: a friend has pointed out that since I am working with flask, Jinja probably has a way of getting the value of these parameters

Comment: i'm a bit lost as to what exactly you're asking. would love to help if you can create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I created hidden values and used Jinja2 to access current url parameters and set default values in case they weren't set yet

```
<form method="GET">
            <select name ="date range" onchange="this.form.submit()" value="last week">
                <option value="today">Today</option>
                <option value="current week">Current week</option>
                <option value="last week">Last week</option>
                <option value="current month">Current month</option>
                <option value="last month">Last month</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="days" value={{request.args.get('days', 30)}} />
            <input type="hidden" name="weeks" value={{request.args.get('weeks', 4)}} />
            <input type="hidden" name="months" value={{request.args.get('months', 4)}} />
            <input type="hidden" name="filter" value={{request.args.get('filter', 'version')}} />

        </form>
```